# mySQL: Slave not able to connect to Master for replication

Tags: amazon-ec2, mysql-replication, master-slave

On my master, I did:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

On my slave, I see:

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 12.34.56.78
                  Master_User: repluser
                  Master_Port: 6666
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File:
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File:
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: mydb
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 0
              Relay_Log_Space: 107
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1045
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'repluser@12.34.56.78:6666' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
```

And it just hangs. But if I try to connect via `mysql -u repluser -h 12.23.45.67 -P 6666 p`, I can connect to the master just fine.

My port, 6666 is open and allowable.

Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on http://nerdherd.com/archives/524

`Note the error code 1045, which indicates a credentials problem.  Double-check the length of your password; MySQL has a MASTER_PASSWORD maximum length limit of 32 characters.  Shorten that puppy up and have another try.`

Answer (score 0):

I needed a name for my slave in SERVER, so i called it as `servidor`, just as the next:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'servidor'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'servidor';
```

The next line on server was:

```
MASTER STATUS
```

And I got the next:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+ 
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000005 |     1232 | pizzeria     |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

So I need to call in the client as the next:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='172.25.3.44', MASTER_USER='servidor'  
MASTER_PASSWORD='servidor', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000005', 
MASTER_LOG_POS=1232;
```